# Temporarily GPU Suggestion Purchase

Tags: graphics-cards

Because of the shortage of AMD Vega cards. I have decide to move to a smaller video card upgrade now and wait on getting one of those Vega cards.

I am looking at pick up at a store close to Houston, Texas if possible. Fry's electronic or Micro Center or maybe best buy something.

I am only willing to spend up to $200 at the most for a PCI-E card.

I am trying to find one that isn't a side-grade or worse perform than what I have in my current PC. It is a GTX 660.

I noticed that most GTX upgrade ending up being too similar to GTX 660 and not having enough of an incentive to buy those at $200 or under. Am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A used GTX 1060 6GB or a new GTX 1060 3GB would be a lot faster than your GTX 660
http://www.anandtech.com/bench/product/1778?vs=1771
Or a Radeon 470 (prices are high now, but it was selling for $140-$160 not long ago)
http://www.anandtech.com/bench/product/1778?vs=1872

But you might as well be patient..

Comment: The problem isn't patient but testing the motherboard making sure it is not dead on arrival. I did not have a spare video card do that. Hence the low price constriction. The deadline is August 28th for RMA on motherboard. By the time Vega 56 comes out it will be too late.

Comment: but you need a CPU anyway - doesn't it have an iGPU?

Comment: Not this one. X370 pro gaming + amd 1700x. My current PC still runs amd 2 1075T CPU + 8 GB DDR3 at 1333 MHZ ever since I put it together 3 years ago. So this will be a huge upgrade. Hence the better performance constriction.

Comment: indeed huge upgrade - the 1075T should have limited the performance
can't you just get some used $10 GPU to test it? or borrow from a friend?

Comment: I don't think I have any unused video card. I already asked a few people I know who have build their PC. Out of luck. I looked at local store most have 1060 for little above $200.